# heroku toolbelt not running on Windows XP

Tags: heroku

I downloaded the latest toolbelt for Windows; however, when I try to launch any heroku command from DOS I get:

c:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:126:in `fork': fork() function is unimplemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)
        from c:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:126:in`background_update!'
        from c:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:111:in `inject_libpath'
        from c:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku:19:in`'

My purpose is to deploy a Play! app on heroku. I'm using Windows XP SP3. Anybody to enlighten me because I'm having headache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. My solution was to comment out the call to `fork`.

Navigate to your Heroku installation directory, and find the file `updater.rb` in the subdirectory `lib\heroku`.

Comment out lines 126 (should be `pid = fork do`), 143 (`end`) and 144 (`Process.detach.pid`).

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In your home directory (i.e. `C:/Users/xxx/.heroku/autoupdate.last`) create a file called "autoupdate.last".

See updater.rb:

```
File.join(Heroku::Helpers.home_directory, ".heroku", "autoupdate.last")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a co-worker on Windows 7 who had this problem.  He accidentally installed ruby 1.8.7.  This error seems to occur when you are using ruby 1.8.7 with a current version of the Heroku Toolbelt (2.32.9 at this writing).  Heroku Toolbelt seems to prefer Ruby 1.9.x.  You can run *gem install heroku*, and the error goes away, but you will get warnings about the heroku gem being deprecated which means it will probably be missing current features.  Update to ruby 1.9.x if you can.  While valid in some cases, editing ruby files should be a last resort in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which of these fixed issue, but one or both of them did:
1. Deselected "hidden" Users/[user]/.heroku" folder.
2. Deselected "read" only for folder.